# Twilio trigger Python function on SMS receive

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, twilio, twilio-api

Utilizing Twilio, upon receiving any SMS I'm seeking to trigger a Python function that reads the contents of the message, then conditionally performs an action.

I'm referencing from Twilio docs right now (.py):

```
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import Client


# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages('MMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').fetch()

print(message.to)
```

Does anyone know how to automatically set up a trigger OnReceive?

Answer (score 0):

The example you show fetches a known message (a message that has already been received and you know its ID).

In order to have a script that is triggered by incoming message you need to setup a [webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/webhook-events) and you need to have an endpoint (server) where you can pick up a trigger sent to you by twilio (eg at *www.yourdomain.com/sms*).

You might not be able to do it just from within a raspbery pi connected to the internet. You need to setup a trigger somewhere on a server, store the incoming messages somehow and then one solution would be to keep polling the server from raspberry pi, fetching new messages and clearing the list.